# pass user principle from spring rest layer to ejb layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ejb

I'm creating Spring REST API for EJB 3 project, i'm securing the REST with spring security.
my problem is how to pass logged in principle from spring to EjbContext so i keep using
`sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal()` in EJB code

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does your Spring Security setup look like?

Comment: i made some research but didn't get any useful results. I'm using spring security with basic auth and default settings, and spring and EJB integrated as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#ejb)

Comment: any ideas or thoughts?